# C# get user's current pc in a domain

Tags: c#, dns, wmi-query

I want to enter the logon ID and to receive the current PC that the account is logged.
I found a code with WMI, but running on 10,000+ computers takes a very long while (~ I gave up after 10 minutes.)
What I do is checking who is logged in every computer until there is a match between logged account and searched account.

```
private void getCurrentUser()
    {
        try
        {
            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + DOMAIN);
            DirectorySearcher dSearch = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
            dSearch.Filter = ("objectCategory=computer");
            foreach (SearchResult result in dSearch.FindAll())
            {
                ManagementScope theScope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + result.Properties["cn"][0].ToString() + "\\root\\cimv2");
                ObjectQuery theQuery = new ObjectQuery("SELECT username FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");
                ManagementObjectSearcher theSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(theScope, theQuery);
                ManagementObjectCollection theCollection = theSearcher.Get();
                foreach (ManagementObject theCurObject in theCollection)
                {
                    if (theCurObject["username"].ToString() == "LAS\\" + USERNAME)
                        Computer1.Text = result.Properties["cn"][0].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
    }
```

this is the code, it works but I would like to know if there is another way to do that without waiting so long or how can I do it quickly?